# how to push to another page by clicking on a item in a data model in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hello I am working on a xamarin forms app that displays data collections in a cardview. What I am trying to do is when the user taps on a card it takes you to another page

here is my card data view model code:

```
using appname.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace appname.ViewModel
{
    public class CardDataViewModel
    {
        public IList<CardDataModel> CardDataCollection { get; set; }

        public object SelectedItem { get; set; }

        public CardDataViewModel()
        {
            CardDataCollection = new List<CardDataModel>();
            GenerateCardModel();
        }

        private void GenerateCardModel()
        {
            // for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                CardDataCollection = new ObservableCollection<CardDataModel>
                {
                    new CardDataModel(typeof(FindArtistsPage))
                    {
                         HeadLines ="Find Artists Near You" ,
                         ProfileImage = "Person_7.jpg",
                         HeadLinesDesc = "Find Pefromers Near your location",
                         // Code to go another page should go here
                    },
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my card code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace appname.ViewModel
{
    public class Cards 
    { 
        public Cards (string name, string image)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Image = image;
        }

        public string Name { private set; get; }

        public string Image { private set; get; }
    }
}
```

and finally here is my card data model code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace appname.Model
{
    public class CardDataModel
    {
        public CardDataModel(Type type)
        {
        }

        public string HeadTitle { get; set; }
        public string HeadLines { get; set; }
        public string HeadLinesDesc { get; set; }
        public string ProfileImage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

EDIT I forgot to put the xaml code for the card Ui here is that code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
              xmlns:local="clr-namespace:appname"
             xmlns:view="clr-namespace:appname.View;assembly=appname"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:appname.ViewModel;assembly=appname"
             x:Class="appname.HomePage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewModel:CardDataViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="White">

        <ListView x:Name="listView" SelectedItem="{Binding SelcetedItem,Mode=TwoWay}" 
              RowHeight="150" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding CardDataCollection}" HasUnevenRows="True"  >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <view:CardViewTemplate/>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

And the CardViewTemplate Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="appname.View.CardViewTemplate"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:appname">
    <Frame IsClippedToBounds="True"
         HasShadow="True"
         BackgroundColor="#443b3e" >
        <Frame.OutlineColor>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color"
                  Android="Gray"
                  iOS="Gray"/>
        </Frame.OutlineColor>
        <Frame.Margin>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                  Android="7" iOS="7"/>
        </Frame.Margin>
        <Frame.Padding>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                  Android="5" iOS="5"/>
        </Frame.Padding>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

            <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            Padding="0"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Start" >
                    <controls:CircleImage Source="{Binding ProfileImage}" VerticalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30"></controls:CircleImage>
                    <Label FontAttributes="None"
               Grid.Row="0"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
               FontSize="12"
               Text="{Binding HeadTitle , Mode = TwoWay}" TextColor="White"  >
                    </Label>



                </StackLayout>
                <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label FontAttributes="None"
               Grid.Row="1"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Start"
               FontSize="30"
               Text="{Binding HeadLines, Mode = TwoWay}" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center">

                        </Label>
                        <Image Source="{Binding  ProfileImage}"  Grid.Row="2"  WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40" HorizontalOptions="End" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="2"
              BackgroundColor="Transparent"
              Padding="4">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0"
                 Grid.Column="0"
                 />
                    <Label Grid.Row="0"
                 Grid.Column="0"
                 Text="{Binding HeadLinesDesc}" HorizontalOptions="Start" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                </Grid>

            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
</ContentView>
```

I have tried googling everything I could before posting this so any help would be amazing!

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical/

Comment: @Jason thanks for the link however those only work with button clicks I do not have a button that can be clicked the cards appear based on whats in the CardDataModel any other suggestions? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what makes you think that it only works with button clicks?  Is the problem that you don't understand Navigation in Forms, or that you don't understand how to capture a tapped event on your Card?  Or something else?  Please be specific about the problem.

Comment: How do you display the cards? Via ContentPage or ContentView? In a list format?

Comment: @ADimaano the cards are displayed in a list view I have updated the question with that xaml page code please check it out let me know your thoughts! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: One more question - can you please post the code for CardViewTemplate?

Comment: @ADimaano I have added the CardViewTeamplate code in the question Please check it out! :)

Comment: There are two approaches I can think of: one is implementing both MessagingCenter and GestureListener, which involves a lot of coding and new files and the other one is GestureRecognizer. Please try [GestureRecognizer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/gestures/tap/) first and see if it satisfies your requirement. Then you can give us feedback here if it doesn't and I will try to walk you through with my other idea.

Answer (score 2):

I will give you some pointers on how to do it, assuming you want to navigate to a Card Specific Page.

First you have a error here `<ListView x:Name="listView" SelectedItem="{Binding SelcetedItem,Mode=TwoWay}"`.. Make it `{Binding SelectedItem}`

Second that binding isn't doing anything. If you want to run something, make it a `Command`and then bind it.

```
public IList<CardDataModel> CardDataCollection { get; set; }

    public ICommand SelectedItem;

    public CardDataViewModel()
    {
        CardDataCollection = new List<CardDataModel>();
        GenerateCardModel();
        SelectedItem = new Command<CardDataModel>(NavigateToCardPage)
    }

    private async void NavigateToCardPage(CardDataModel c)
    {
        await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new CardPage(c));
    }

    private void GenerateCardModel()
    {
        // for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            CardDataCollection = new ObservableCollection<CardDataModel>
            {
                new CardDataModel(typeof(FindArtistsPage))
                {
                     HeadLines ="Find Artists Near You" ,
                     ProfileImage = "Person_7.jpg",
                     HeadLinesDesc = "Find Pefromers Near your location",
                     // Code to go another page should go here
                },
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried your suggestion but I get this error: Error CS0103 The name 'Navigation' does not exist in the current any suggestions on how to fix this error thanks in advance! :)

Comment: @Phoneswapshop Just import any dependencies you need.

Comment: @Phoneswapshop The error is it in Compile time or Runtime ?

Comment: @Phoneswapshop Either way. You must wrap your `HomePage` within a `Navigation Page`. And then you can use the `Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation` code

Comment: I tried you suggestion and that got rid of the error but when I click on the card it does not take me to the FindArtists page any idea why? Thanks for all the help so far! :)

Comment: @Phoneswapshop I would need to see all of your updated code. Btw did you fix the gaf you had in the `Binding Selected` in Xaml ?

Comment: I did fix the issue in the xaml code I will post updated code shortly